# All my snap apps settings are lost after reboot

Tags: firefox, snap

In 23.10, after rebooting, all my snap apps (Firefox, dbeaver, etc.) have lost their settings.
No more plugins, no bookmarks, etc.

Listing files in ~/snap/ shows mostly empty directories.

For example firefox shows:

```
 ➜ ll ~/snap/firefox/
Permissions Size User   Date Modified  Name
lrwxrwxrwx     4 franck 10 juin  12:19  current -> 2760
```

2760 does not exist.

dbeaver shows:

```
 ➜ ll ~/snap/dbeaver-ce/
Permissions Size User   Date Modified  Name
drwxr-xr-x     - franck  2 nov.  10:24  257/
drwxr-xr-x     - franck  8 oct.  21:09  262/
drwxr-xr-x     - franck  2 nov.  10:42  266/
drwxr-xr-x     - franck 10 juin  19:15  common/
lrwxrwxrwx     3 franck  2 nov.  10:42  current -> 266/
```

and common is empty,as well a 266...

How can this be ?

nb: I had a snapd update popup just after this dreadful reboot.

Comment: Check in ~/.mozilla/firefox, are your profiles there?

Comment: Try running `/snap/firefox/current/usr/lib/firefox/firefox`, does that get your bookmarks back? For me, this causes firefox to look into `~/.mozilla/firefox` for whatever reason